# java script бот telegram для новичков

Tags: javascript

собираюсь заняться кодингом уже более двух лет, но все никак, вот, решил наконец-то взятся за голову. подскажите пожалуйста хорошие статьи для кодинга на джаве, желательно боты телеграм, дискорд

Comment: так java или javascript?

Comment: java script ////

Comment: ссылки выше....

Comment: ознакомлюсь, благодарю